# Show that if ($x_n$) converges to $x$, then $d(x_n, A)$ converges to $d(x, A)$ for each fixed subset A of E

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that that if ($x_n$) converges to $x$, then $d(x_n, A)$ converges to $d(x, A)$ for each fixed subset $A$ of $E$ ?

Comment: Prove that $x\mapsto d(x.A)$ is $1$-Lipschitz. Conclude.

Comment: Depends on what you take to be the distance $d(x,A)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume that $A \neq \emptyset$.

For $a \in A$, $d(x_n,a) \leq d(x_n, x) + d(x, a)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus, $d(x_n, A) \leq d(x_n,x) + d(x,a)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in A$.

So, $d(x_n, A) - d(x_n, x) \leq d(x,A)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
i.e., $d(x_n, A) - d(x,A) \leq d(x_n, x)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Similarly, we can obtain that $d(x, A) - d(x_n,A) \leq d(x_n, x)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

It follows that $|d(x_n, A) - d(x,A) | \leq d(x_n, x)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $| \cdot |$ denotes the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}$.

By letting $n \rightarrow \infty$, we complete the proof. $\quad \square$